# why show the different in same function at different browser

Tags: javascript, php, css

I created a draggable widget that is working nicely in localhost and chrome, but in  firefox it didn't work properly

this code also I included

```
 moz-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
```

can you give some suggestions

Comment: looks like you missed the `-` for the first rule

Comment: Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in your Mozilla rule. Anyway, try the following CSS to achieve a full cross-browser compatibility:

```
.my_element
{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
}
```